# how to store location and time stamp data using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

how to store location and time stamp data generated by the buses every 2 minutes on different routes using Neo4j.

Route 1 : 
A-> B->    C->  D->  C->  B->  A [route created in neo4j] how to achieve below time-stamp storing?

8:01  8:10  8:25 9:10 9:xx xxx  xxx

x:x   xx:xx xx:xx xx:x x:x  X:X

Route 2: 
G->  G->    H->  I->  J->  K->  L 
10:01  10:10  10:25 11:10 12:xx xxx 
x:x   xx:xx xx:xx xx:x x:x  X:X 

In rdbms, i store the time with each bustop as column id. How to do this neo4j. Stuck with my college project, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give us a description of your current data model? I think your problem is related to your actual data model.

Comment: i have access database. one table has the Bus stops as columns and the time at which bus reached the various stops in the whole day is given as  the records. My concern is how to represent this in the Ne04j, the bus makes 100 trips a day as its in the college campus. And it would have at-least some 20 stops in the route. Similarly, i have some 23 buses running parallel. So how to represent this in neo4j for analysis.

Comment: I'll think about it and I'll reply using a data model. I think the problem is not technical, it's just the data model :)

Answer (score 2):

To create a good data model, you have to wonder what you will be looking for in your datas.

Here, you will be looking for a timestamp (or at least an HH:mm data) to know when a bus will reach a stop.

### So, you will need two nodes:

```
:Bus
    id: integer (Unique id for the bus)
    route: integer (I suppose you have bus numbers)

:Stop
    id: integer (unique id for the stop)
    location: string (I don't know if you have the GPS coordinates, but you can store them using a string)
    name: string (your stops are having a name I guess)
```

### And one relationship:

```
:REACHED
    date: timestamp
```

### Example model (PNG extracted from neo4j web interface)

[image: Example graph description]

So, when a bus reaches a stop, you simply have to create one relation between your bus node and the stop node he just reached, using `timestamp()` neo4j method to generate the exact timestamp of the creation of your relation.

Then, to match every stop of a bus, you can extract the timestamp value from `REACHED` relationship.

Comment: That's really a good direction to me and really appreciate your help. <br>Another important question i have is, since this is a college internal bus system, stops are close by, and time-stamp data gets generated every 2 minutes. So at stop-1 for 20 rounds a day, should i just keep the time stamp maintained in a list or hash or some thing like that. i want all the reached-time data for the future analysis. So, how do we usually store such information in neo4j, do we use some data-structure sort of thing to store thousands of time-stamps that would come in a month?

Comment: Well, in fact you don't have to store any timestamp in an array. as I said if you want to get every bus stop from a stop, you can gather it from relations: `MATCH (:Stop{location: "yourlocation"})-[r:REACHED]-() return r.date`

Comment: yeah i can get the bus-reached results that way, but my question is, Since the bus 121 comes to the stop -Reached node every "30 minutes", how to store that data? the model that you gave overwrites the previous value of the time-stamp. For example, if a bus comes to reached stop at 10:00 AM and comes back again in the back trip and again in the next trip so on.... so how to  store all those time stamps of the bus reaching the stop at various trips/rounds.

Comment: You can create multiple relationships between two nodes. the Bus 121 node and the stop 150 can have multiple relationships, even if they have the same name. So, using `Match (b:Bus{number: 121})-[r:REACHED]->(s:Stop{number:150}) return b,r,s` Can return one bus, one stop and as much relationships as you need