# store a hash-map continer type of data on edge of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to store lots of data into buckets or different hash-maps between two nodes on their edges. Basically there is lot of data getting generated related to the two nodes and i want to keep the data over their edge in a hash. Since the context matters, the edge should have different buckets/hasmaps so that i can write data into and return data from the data written over the edges. How to do this in neo4j, any reference articles please.

Answer (score -1):

Consider that properties are already an hash map key/value. Regarding the context you can have multiple edges between two nodes one for each context. If the contexts are limited and pre-defined you can use a specific name to the relationship that identify the context, otherwise you can add a 'context' property that allow you to identify the context.

How much data do you plan to store? How many keys in the hash map?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712447/how-to-store-location-and-time-stamp-data-using-neo4j

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712447/how-to-store-location-and-time-stamp-data-using-neo4j This is what i'm trying to achieve. As one advised, lets suppose i follow the same model shared. In such case, i get time-stamp of reached bus every 20 Minutes on average(after each trip it comes to the same node in next 20 mins). so how should i store info over the edge, if i have key like : <timeOfRoute111busReachedHere: value(timestamp)> .But, since my value/time-stamp is generated every 20 minutes, how should store all time-stamps,so that in future,i may run some metrics

Comment: But properties are a fixed set of keys right?   That's not the same as having a key-value store, as the OP commented.